# pushed items to array seem to be reactive to old object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I am facing an issue where after I push an object to an array it will be reactive to changes.

```
// actions.js
export const addToCart = ({ commit }) => {
    commit('addToCart'); // properly commits to change the state

    setTimeout(function () {
        commit('resetToppings');
    }, 10000);
};


// mutations.js
export const addToCart = (state) => {
    state.cart.push(state.orderItem);
};

export const resetToppings = (state) => {
    state.orderItem.toppings = [];
};


// state.js
cart: [],
orderItem: {
    quantity: 1,
    toppings: [],
},
```

The `orderItem` gets properly pushed to the `cart`, but 10 seconds later when I `resetToppings`, it resets the toppings inside the `cart` as well as in the `orderItem`.

How can I make sure that `resetToppings` does not mutate anything inside `cart`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you push `state.orderItem` you add a reference to it in the array. So when `state.orderItem` changes, the element inside the array changes, because it (the element inside the array) is actually still pointing to the same (`state.orderItem`) object.

You can push a shallow clone of the `orderItem` object instead:

```
// mutations.js
export const addToCart = (state) => {
    state.cart.push({...state.orderItem});
};
```

This way what is added to the array is a different object.

Note: you can do:

```
state.cart.push({...state.orderItem});
```

But this will only work if you never remove/add elements from/to the `toppings` array directly *after* the `addToCart` is called. That is, if you call `resetToppings` before adding new elements to `toppings` (which will work because `resetToppings` assigns a new array).

If that's not always the case, I mean, if you sometimes edit the `toppings` array directly *after* the `addToCart` is called, you might want to clone it as well:

```
state.cart.push(Object.assign({...state.orderItem}, {toppings: [...state.orderItem.toppings]}});
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your explanation. You are heaven sent!